# Imprimir valor fuera de foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo generado un listado que se genera de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach ($productos as $p) { 
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->codigoProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->categoriaNombre . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->marcaNombre . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->detalleProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->precioProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

Como categoría se repite, me gustaría imprimirla una sola vez de modo que quede

```
Categoria
Código | Marca | Detalle | Precio
1
2
3
...
```

Pero no logro llamar el valor del campo fuera del `foreach`.

Comment: Las respuestas que he leído ignoran el rendimiento del código. Si, como he entendido, necesitas usar el valor de categoría **una sola vez**, fuera del `foreach`. Ejemplo:  `$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);` puedes acceder al valor conociendo el nombre de la clave: `$valor_de_foo=$array["foo"]` eso puedes hacerlo fuera del bucle for, de modo que no tengas que asignar la variable varias veces cuando sólo la necesitas una vez. Aunque me pregunto **si no hay un error en la lógica de tu programa que te hace obtener varias veces un valor que sólo usarás una vez**.

Comment: No esta bien que traigas de la base de datos un set de datos y solamente imprimas un solo valor eso indica que hay alguna deficiencia en tu modelo de datos pienso que lo mejor seria crear otro metodo que haga un 'select disctint' asi eliminas la duplicidad

Answer (score 1):

@Maru, elaborando mi respuesta anterior:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->categoriaNombre, $b->categoriaNombre);
}
usort($productos, "cmp");

$categoria = false;

foreach ($productos as $p) { 
    if ($p->categoriaNombre != $categoria) {
        echo '<tr>'; 
        echo '<td colspan="4">' . $p->categoriaNombre . '</td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';
        $categoria = $p->categoriaNombre; 
    }

    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->codigoProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->marcaNombre . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->detalleProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->precioProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

Yo creo que esto es exactamente lo que necesitas.

También te podría interesar añadir un `htmlentities()` a todos los campos.

Comment: Muchas gracias jotaelesalinas!
Estoy haciendo pruebas y de momento funciona!

Comment: @Maru ¡De nada! Por favor, si te funciona marca la respuesta como buena.

Answer (score 0):

Si categoría se te repite puedes guardarla una variable para que la utilices fuera del `foreach` te dejo el ejemplo:

```
foreach ($productos as $p) { 
    $categoria = $p->categoriaNombre;
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->codigoProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->marcaNombre . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->detalleProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->precioProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>'; 
}

echo $categoria;
```

Nota: si el valor de categoría cambia te va a colocar el último valor que se guardó.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría usar un `array` para guardar tu variable categoría en caso de repetirse o repetirse un valor más de una vez:

```
foreach ($productos as $p) { 
    $categoria = $p->categoriaNombre;
    $vars_región = array("categoria");
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->codigoProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->marcaNombre . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->detalleProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $p->precioProducto . '</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

Y al final del `foreach` lo imprimes.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es **agrupar** por categoría escribiendo el nombre de la categoría y después los productos de esa categoría, haz lo siguiente:

- ordena los `$productos` por categoría
- crea una variable `$categoria` igual a `false`
- en el bucle, comprueba si `$p->categoriaNombre == $categoria`
- si no es igual, escribe la categoría y asigna `$categoria = $p->categoriaNombre;`
- escribe todos los datos del producto como haces ahora, excepto la categoría

Perdona que no escriba más código pero es que estoy con el móvil.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías intentar con un foreach dentro de otro, uno para iterar las categorías y otro para iterar los productos dentro de la misma, aquí un ejemplo basico:

```
$categorias = cargar_categorias()

foreach( $categorias as $cat){
   echo $cat->nombre;
   $productos = cargar_productos($cat->id);

   foreach( $productos as $prod ){
      echo $prod->nombre;
      echo $prod->precio;
   }
}
```

saludos.